# ssh sudo to a different user execute commands on remote Linux server

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, sudo

We have a password less authentication between the server for root user, I am trying to run the alias on remote server as below

```
#ssh remoteserver runuser -l wasadmin wasstart
```

But it is not working.  Any suggestions or any other method to achieve it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What do you mean by "not working"? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: You should add the new information editing the question and not posting an answer. You can solve the issue running the configuration script where the alias is defined. `ssh remoteserver runuser -l wasadmin "/path/to/script/with/aliases; wasstart"`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments as you need to sudo to wasadmin in order to run wasadmin, you can try this:

```
ssh remoteserver 'echo /path/to/wasadmin wasstart | sudo su - wasadmin'
```

Comment: Problem is we don’t have direct access to wasadmin.  So we need to use either sudo su - wasadmin or runuser -l wasadmin

Comment: I am using root account which has password less authentication from jump server.

Comment: runuser is a command in Linux with that can used to run different user

Comment: @DharmaPunniyaMoorthy - see the updated answer, try if that works.

Answer (score 0):

For add an alias in linux you must run

```
alias youcommandname=‘command’
```

Notice:
This will work until you close or exit from current shell . To fix this issue just add this to you .bash_profile and run source .bash_profile
Also your profile file name depending on which shell you using . bash , zsh ,...

Comment: Alias already exist. My intention is to trigger the alias from remote server